# Running code in multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to run code on an Excel document that has compiled data. I am running two macros individually on each sheet. I am unable to run this macro on all the worksheets in this workbook. First macro is for sorting the columns:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim ws As WorkSheet
Range("Sort").Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=ws.Range("q66"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=ws.Range("u66") _
    , Order2:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:= _
    False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
Next WS
End Sub
```

Second macro is for hiding the rows based on value "Null":

```
Sub HideList()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In ws.Range("HideList")
    With cell
        .EntireRow.Hidden = _
            (Value = "Empty")
    End With
 Next ws

 End Sub
```

It works if I remove the `ws`. from the range but again works only for single sheet.

Comment: You need to set the ws either through a `For Each ws in activeworkbook.sheets` or set each individual sheet `Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: I did, but I get errors    Sub Macro1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Range("Sort").Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("q66"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("u66") _
        , Order2:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:= _
        False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
Next ws
End Sub

Comment: The `Range("Sort")` likely has a workbook scope. You cannot use it on individual worksheets. Better to define each worksheet's sorting range 'manually'. See [this recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33661309/streamline-a-recorded-macro-that-spans-over-multiple-tabs-and-sorts-on-different/33661909#33661909).

Answer (score 0):

You still have a couple ranges that do not reference the relevant worksheet. Update as follows:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim ws As WorkSheet
For Each ws in activeworkbook.sheets 
 ws.Range("Sort").Sort Key1:=ws.Range("q66"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=ws.Range("u66") _
    , Order2:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:= _
    False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
Next WS
End Sub

Sub Delete_Name_Date()
   Dim cell As Range
For Each ws in activeworkbook.sheets 
    For Each cell In ws.Range("R66:R306")
      With cell
        .EntireRow.Hidden = _
            (.Value = "Empty")
       End With
    Next
next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the macro. The second macro is working fine across the spreadsheet. The first one fails with run time error 1004 "Method Range of object _Worksheet failed". ws.Range is whats causing the issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have a range named "Sort" on each worksheet of the workbook?